# JWT not return SigningKey

Tags: go, jwt

I am trying to implement JWT for REST
I'm just curious on this code below

```
    var mySigningKey = []byte("mysecret")

    token, err := jwt.Parse(r.Header["Token"][0], func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("There was an error")
            }
            return mySigningKey, nil
        })
        fmt.Println(token)
```

I expect token will return mySigningKey value but its return Token value

[image]

that shoud return value inside mySigningKey right?

Or did I misunderstand some concept?

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#Parse The callback function must select a key, but `jwt.Parse` would always return you a token.

Answer (score 0):

By calling Parse method on your header Token value you are creating the token struct. If you want to get your SigningString you need to call SigningString() method on your token variable.

```
// Generate the signing string.  This is the
// most expensive part of the whole deal.  Unless you
// need this for something special, just go straight for
// the SignedString.
func (t *Token) SigningString() (string, error) {
    var err error
    parts := make([]string, 2)
    for i, _ := range parts {
        var source map[string]interface{}
        if i == 0 {
            source = t.Header
        } else {
            source = t.Claims
        }

        var jsonValue []byte
        if jsonValue, err = json.Marshal(source); err != nil {
            return "", err
        }

        parts[i] = EncodeSegment(jsonValue)
    }
    return strings.Join(parts, "."), nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function which is the second argument to `Parse` is responsible for providing the signing key which will be used to verify the JWT signature is correct.

In the case illustrated in the question, the signing key is a constant because HMAC is used to sign it.

However, if you had a RSA keypair, the token header would be useful to pick the right public key to check the signature, perhaps pulling it down from a well known JWKS endpoint.